Double-check what you're pushing
One of the things that can make git hard to think about is that there are at least four different "repositories" you're shuffling files between: your worktree, the index, your local repo, and your upstream repo.
To see the differences between your worktree and your index (to see what you need to add), you can use git diff.
To see the differences between your index and your local repo (to see what you're about to commit), you can use git diff --cached.
But extending the pattern, is there a good way to view differences between your local repo and your upstream, before you do a git push, to double-check that what you're about to push is what you really want to push?
I ask because it's not actually that hard to push things you didn't mean to push.  For example, if you've done something like a git merge --nocommit on your local branch, I believe that gives you a bunch of "invisible" local changes, that git diff will never show, but that will affect your upstream repo — in ways you maybe didn't intend — next time you push.

Update: Whoops, the "Check your question" thingie didn't detect any dups, but a google search did:

How can I see what I am about to push with git?

List Git commits not pushed to the origin yet

Preview a Git push

How to list unpushed Git commits (local but not on origin)


I haven't digested the answers to those yet, but as soon as I do, I'll probably delete this question.

"is there a good way to view differences between your local repo and your upstream, before you do a git push" git fetch and then (if this branch is mybranch) git diff origin/mybranch mybranch. (It might help to use a good external interface for git diff.)

While there is one answer in all the linked questions that has a gitk screenshot it does not tell to use the --all argument and it does in my opinion not so good job of explaining what gitk is capable of showing so I am adding an answer here.


Is there a good way to view differences between your local repo and your upstream, before you do a git push, to double-check that what you're about to push is what you really want to push?

Yes: gitk --all will show everything you need:

Changes in worktree
Changes in the index
Changes in local repo
Changes in upstream repo


(The first two points will not show up when there are no changes)

But the OP wants a list of files.

Select F3, then right-click on M5 and select "show diff". A list of files that have changed will be shown.
